# disk size on ubuntu in virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 on virtual box 4+ and allocated 8 GB for a dynamically allocated hard disk.

At a very early stage when using that machine I got a notification that there is no space left on the disk even though only 2.8 GB were used (checked from both within the machine and VBX). Now I'm not able to open the machine anymore, it is stack after the "checking battery stage" line. when I run "xinit" manually I get an error that there is no disk space.

Any idea why the disk is not increasing to the full 8 GB?

EDIT: I've booted from CD and now see the system partition is full. I am not able to increase or move it even though there is a huge unallocated space. see image.

EDIT 2: I was able to increase the sysrtem partition using GParted and now the system works. I initialy did not use GParted correctly.

[image]

Comment: Is the physical hard drive you put the virtual disk on full ?

Comment: no, far from that

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to mount this virtual disk from a live CD, then just use 'du' with sensible parameters to see where is the problem.

Use 'du -hscx /*' as a starting point.